# sudden current dropping identifying circuit

Tags: switches, current-measurement, electrode

Here is my scenario:

I have a pair of electrodes in my device and it is submerged in seawater, so there is a current.

Once I take it out the current drops and I want to implement a circuit to identify the sudden drop of the current.

The drop will not be same every time because sometime there is some algae and because of that even though I take it out some amount of current is still there.

I don't want to use a microcontroller here. I would like to have a circuit designed to do the exact same thing, and it should be designed the way as it is using a minimum amount of power.

I want to design a switch which will turn on when its take out from the seawater

Comment: You've told us what you want but didn't ask a question. I suspect that you haven't developed a specification yet either. You need something like, "What methods could be used to detect and signal a DC current decreasing by 0.72 A in 3.5 s with a nominal current of 12 to 27 A?"

Comment: Ask a question. You'll feel better for it.

Comment: It should be a simple circuit that operates with 5V and mAs

Comment: You have edited your question but still have no specification and no question. ("*I want to design a switch*" is not a question.) Where are you stuck.

Comment: How rapid is the drop in current? A time value would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Should the current be the result of galvanic action caused by two different metal electrodes in sea water, it could be used to generate a '0' output which would become a '1' once the electrodes are withdrawn from the sea water.

[image]

Otherwise, should the conductivity between two identical metal electrodes in sea water be responsible for the current flow in the external circuit, the logic would be inverted.

[image]